# When streaming tweets with Python Twitter I get the error message: OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

Tags: pyopenssl

I got this error where I have no clue where it come from and where to start to debug. I do not understand this error at all. I'll just post my code here. I utilized multithreading in my code to periodically save the tweets on separate files. My program will work fine for maybe over 10 days, and then throw me this error message. Maybe twitter reset my connection?

```
import twitter
import json
import time

from tqdm import tqdm
import string
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

import threading
import os

consumer_key = '*'
consumer_secret = '*'
access_token_key = '*'
access_token_secret = '*'

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = consumer_key,\
                  consumer_secret = consumer_secret,\
                  access_token_key = access_token_key,\
                  access_token_secret = access_token_secret)

os.chdir('*/social_media/streamed_tweets')

#multiThreading class and functions starts here
class timerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, stoptime, stopevent): #remember to change args accordingly
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.stoptime = stoptime
        self.stopevent = stopevent
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        twiTimer(self.stoptime, self.stopevent)
        print("Exiting " + self.name)

class streamerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, keywords, stop): #remember to change args accordingly
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.stop = stop
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        twiStream(self.keywords, self.stop)
        print("Exiting " + self.name)

def twiTimer(stop_time, stop_event):
    while True:
        now1 = datetime.now()
        t = str(now1.timetz())
        if t[:8] == stop_time: #make it t[:8] for daily loop
            stop_event.set()
            print('stop triggered')
            time.sleep(1) #wait to pass the '00' time
        time.sleep(0.1)

def twiStream(keywords, stop_event):
    while True:
        stream = api.GetStreamFilter(track = keywords, languages=['en'], filter_level = None)
        now2 = datetime.now()
        filename = str(now2.date())+'.txt' #change this to date() for daily loop
        f = open(filename, 'w+')
        stop_event.clear() #reset the event
        print(now2)
        with tqdm() as pbar:
            while not stop_event.is_set():
                counter = 2
                for tweet in stream:
                    if counter <= 0:
                        break
                    f.write(json.dumps(tweet))
                    f.write('\n')
                    pbar.update()
                    counter -= 1
        f.close()
        time.sleep(0.5)
#multiThreading class and functions ends here

def main():
    keywords = ['*']

stop = threading.Event()
stop_at = '00:00:00' #make it '00:00:00' for daily loop

#count = 10

thread1 = timerThread(1, 'timerThread', stop_at, stop)
thread2 = streamerThread(2, 'streamerThread', keywords, stop)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print("Exiting Main Thread")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Exception in thread streamerThread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 285, in recv_into

    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1814, in recv_into

    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)

File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1631, in _raise_ssl_error

  raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))

OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher

   yield

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 637, in read_chunked

  self._update_chunk_length()

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 569, in _update_chunk_length

   line = self._fp.fp.readline()

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto

   return self._sock.recv_into(b)

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 290, in recv_into

   raise SocketError(str(e))

OSError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 749, in generate

   for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 461, in stream

  for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 665, in read_chunked

  self._original_response.close()

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__

 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 349, in _error_catcher

   raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner

   self.run()

File "streamer.py", line 48, in run
twiStream(self.keywords, self.stop)

 File "streamer.py", line 72, in twiStream

  for tweet in stream:

  File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 4575, in GetStreamFilter

  for line in resp.iter_lines():

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 793, in iter_lines

   for chunk in self.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size, decode_unicode=decode_unicode):

 File "/home/abe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 752, in generate

  raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)

requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same error.

Comment: @Miguel: Unfortunately I did not solve. I don't know where to start. I simply check my program every few days, and restart my program if it runs into this error. Fortunately the project I was working does not require me to collect 100% of the streamed tweets. I build this program just because I wanted to collect as much as I can.